# Rendering custom template tags from database in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am pretty new to Django and am trying to build a blog app for my website.  I have a model I have created to store blog posts that includes a text field for the post body, created and converted to HTML using TinyMCE (via Grappelli).  I would like embed custom template tags within this post body that are saved in the database as the template tag, but then rendered as HTML when requested on my site.  So far, I am not having any luck getting the tags to render properly.  How can I get Django to correctly interpret and render the template tags within my post?  The custom tag works fine when loaded and implemented directly in a template, it is just this indirect loading that gives me trouble. I tried [this snippet here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1373/) (**Edit:** It works, I just did it wrong!), but it did not work correctly.

Here is my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from myproject.apps.blog.models import Post

def blog_detail_view(request, year, month, day, slug):
    selected_post = Post.objects.get(status=1, pub_date__year = year, pub_date__month = time.strptime(month, "%b")[1], pub_date__day = day, slug = slug)
    return render_to_response('blog/detail.html', locals())
```

And the relevant portion of my template:

```
...
{% load my_custom_tag %}

<div class="entry">
    {{ selected_post.body|safe }}
</div>
...
```

Here is an example of the text saved to `Post.body`:

```
My first paragraph.
{% my_custom_tag var1 var2 %}
My second paragraph.
```

Currently, this will render as :

```
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<p>{% my_custom_tag var1 var2 %}</p>
<p>My second paragraph.</p>
```

When I want something like this:

```
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<p><a href="var1"><img src="var2"></a></p>
<p>My second paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the `render_as_template` tag found [here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1373/) DOES work, I just misunderstood it.  Beginner's mistake.  There are two things that were not specified in the documentation for the snippet that I failed to pick up on my own.

So, you put the `render_as_template` tag in your template like this:

```
{% load render_as_template %}
{% render_as_template myobject.attribute %}
```

Thus allowing any template tags within `myobject.attribute` to be rendered.  Here is where I ran into trouble:

First, I was passing my post body to `render_as_template` as `selected_post.body|truncatewords_html:"100"|safe` or as `selected_post.body|safe`.  The template tag is unable to process the filters on the attribute and seems to interpret them as part of the object's name.  Since this object does not exist, nothing is rendered.  What I need in my template is:

```
{% autoescape off %}
{% filter truncatewords_html:"100" %}
{% render_as_template selected_post.body %}
{% endfilter %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Second, if the content of my post is:

```
My first paragraph.
{% my_custom_tag var1 var2 %}
My second paragraph.
```

Then in order for `my_custom_tag` to be interpreted, I need to add to my post:

```
{% load my_custom_tag %}
```

Now it works perfectly!

Comment: I have almost same problem. But i have static in my template tag. when i do render_as_template content i get Invalid block tag: 'static'. Is there any work around for that?

Answer (score 0):

To create custom tags in Django, you need to write a tag function then register it. [Link to Official Django Docs on the subject.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags)

Comment: I already have several custom tags created and registered.  They work fine with my templates when they are not part of my post content (ie. pulled from the database as HTML).